# Will "chkdsk /r" scan the free area of harddisk for physical damages?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, chkdsk

From [microsoft documentation of **chkdsk** command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk), it has the following commonly used switches:

> **/f**
>   Fixes errors on the disk. The disk must be locked. If chkdsk cannot lock the drive, a message appears that asks you if you want to check the drive the next time you restart the computer.
>
> **/r**
>   Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information. The disk must be locked. `/r` includes the functionality of `/f`, with the additional analysis of physical disk errors.
>
> **/b**
>   NTFS only: Clears the list of bad clusters on the volume and rescans all allocated and free clusters for errors. `/b` includes the functionality of `/r`. Use this parameter after imaging a volume to a new hard disk drive.

**Q1:**
Does it mean `/r` switch will scan for both logical errors in files (logical file corruptions) and physical HDD damages (like bad sectors)?

**Q2:**
If **`/r`** switch does scan for bad sectors, will it scan the **entire HDD (both used and free areas)** ?

**Q3:**
Do the differences between `/r` and `/b` lie in that `/r` will skip scanning for the sectors previously marked as bad sectors while `/b` will scan all sectors (no matter normal or bad)?

Therefore, `/b` will update the list of marked bad sectors, which means releasing false-positive bad sectors for normal usage (This often happens when cloning an old HDD with bad sectors to a brand new HDD which should have no bad sectors in ideal case). Am I correct?

**Q4:**
If my understanding is correct in Q3, then I would wonder about the mechanism of determination for bad sectors.

Suppose there is a bad sector(already marked as bad) in old HDD and it is not 100% dead practically, so it could read once in several attempts. Then I clone the old HDD to a brand new one, so the bad sector records are also copied to the new HDD.

If now I run `chkdsk /b` for the brand new HDD, will there be a chance that this abnormal sector will be released as a normal sector for read/write? That sounds dangerous and unreliable.

**Is it worth to use `/b` for the brand new HDD after cloned?**

Comment: Yes for all 4 questions. *That sounds dangerous and unreliable.* Why? *bad sector in old HDD and it is not 100% dead, so it could read once in several attempts* After first failed (write/verify or `chkdsk /r`) attempt it must be marked as bad and it will never be used in future until `format`, `chkdsk /b` or similar action.

Comment: @Moab Will `/b` also scan the entire disk surface?

Comment: According to your research, yes.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for your quick response and clear explanation, would you like to paste your explanation as answer, so I can mark it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly credit to [Akina](https://superuser.com/users/910710/akina)and [Moab](https://superuser.com/users/40928/moab)

Answers for all 4 questions are **yes**.

Furthermore, `/b` switch will scan the entire disk surface.
And after first failed attempt (write/verify or `chkdsk /r`), the bad sector must be marked as bad and it will never be used in future until `format`, `chkdsk /b` or similar action.